# Logging to a RESTful API

Tags: c#, logging

We have situation in a WPF application that we want to send all logs to a service thorough RESTful API. But because the performance is really important we cannot await (or wait) for the logging to get completed so we proposed that when a log created the logging method queues the log in an in-memory collection and fires another thread that actually sends the logs to the service and if in any situations the process cannot be completed due to lost of internet connection or anything else, the logs should be stored in a more permanent data store (file or SQLite,...) so that the thread can retry to sending those later.

That said, my questions:

1. Is this a good workflow or are there any better ones?
2. Are there any logging frameworks or plugins that implement such behavior?

Comment: Using a RESTful API for logging is really not a good idea. Why not use messaging by using an ESB like NServiceBus or Shuttle (https://github.com/Shuttle)? That ensures durability,

Comment: An ESB would be a lot for an application of this size. :)
Why do you think it is not a good idea?

Comment: The dependency on the service availability to perform logging. Also the additional functionality you would need to implement, like retries, if the service is unavailable. I use Shuttle which is a lightweight distributed ESB, which handles retries etc. out of the box.